# In twenty sixteen, show slider in homepage only

Tags: theme-twenty-sixteen

By using the twenty sixteen theme, I placed a "slider" short-code in the `header.php` section. The result, the slider position is where i want it, but it's showing on all pages.

How do i achieve this by making the slider show on the homepage ONLY?

The website is : http://www.pulaakufm.com/

Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

inside of the `header.php` file use `is_home()` to check if it's the home page

```
if ( is_home() ) {
    // Include slider here
}
```